# How to pass an AccountId to a parameter of type <T::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Source?

Tags: pallet, account, data-type

I am using pallet_assets for creating custom assets and I want to call the transfer function from pallet_assets in my other custom pallet. The thing is I want to pass the AccountId of the recipient but the transfer function in pallet_assets does not take AccounId, rather it takes <T::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Source as parameter.

How can I pass AccountId to <T::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Source ??

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
mismatched types
expected associated type `<<T as frame_system::Config>::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Source`
   found associated type `<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId`rustcE0308
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `AccountId` and you want to Get `LookUp<Target = AccountId>`, you will have to [unlookup](https://crates.parity.io/sp_runtime/traits/trait.StaticLookup.html#tymethod.unlookup). Straightforward way to do is:

```rust
let user: AccountId = get_a_user();
let user_lookup = <T::Lookup as sp_runtime::traits::StaticLookup>::unlookup(user.clone());
```